# DAX calculate an average of a column when taking cells that contain only numbers

Tags: excel, dax, powerpivot

Using PowerPivot functionality to create measures.
There are two types of values in a column: integers and NULL (string).
Trying to figure out how to create a DAX formula to calculate an average for the column that would take only cells that contain integers.
It feels that the next basic formula would work:

```
=CALCULATE ( 
        AVERAGE ( tData[columnA]),
        FILTER (    tData, [columnA] <> "NULL" )
               )
```

but it throws an error: The function AVERAGE takes an argument that evaluates to numbers or dates and cannot work with values of type String.

I'm wondering if there is a way to avoid this error without removing/cleaning NULLs values beforehand?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Power BI tables cannot contain mixed types of values in a single column. If there is numbers and texts in a column, the column type is text. Numeric values included in the column is not actually numbers, they are just texts composed of numeric characters.

So, in order to make it work, you need to explicitly convert numeric strings to real numbers.

```
= CALCULATE(
    AVERAGEX( tData[columnA], VALUE(tData[columnA]) ),
    tData[columnA] <> "NULL"
)
```

However, I suggest not to have text and numeric values in one column. Use Power Query to either remove rows with "NULL", or convert them to BLANK.

Answer (score 1):

Best way here would if you replace your `NULL` (string) values with the database `null` (nothing) value. This way your rows stay `null` but your calculation still works.

Go to `Edit Queries > Transform > Repalce Values` and replace your string `NULL` to a database `null`. Your table will look like this then:

[image]

Now the avarage calcualtion is simple:

[image]

Database `null` values get ignored from every calculations. This is way it works.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, though I'm using Power Pivot and it doesn't have that functionality, only if I do it manually but I'm trying to avoid that.

Comment: @Art - PowerPivot has this functionality too.

Comment: @RADO could you give a little bit more details? How can I do that without creating an extra column with an Excel formula?

Comment: Power Pivot has the same Power Query functionality as Power BI. Just google how to use PowerQuery in Excel.